# How do I optimize (increase the speed) of this MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-schema, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "year": { "$year": "$utc_timestamp" },
        "month": { "$month": "$utc_timestamp" },
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$utc_timestamp" },
    },
    "defects": {
        "$sum": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$status", "defect" ] },
            1,
            0
        ]}
    },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$project": {
    "defect_rate": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$defects", 0 ] },
            0,
            { "$divide": [ "$defects", "$totalCount" ] }
        ]
    }
}}
```

])

Right now, it scans about 500,000 documents and takes 6 seconds to complete.

I expect the number of records to increase further, so it's time to optimize it.

What steps should I take to increase the speed of this operation?

I assume `_id` is automatically indexed by MongoDB. Is there anything else?

Comment: Unfortunately, because you're not using any filtering and `aggregate` can't use covered indexes, you're always going to be scanning all 500,000 docs.

Comment: There is no index in use here unless you introduce a `$match` stage at the beginning. Right now you are not "selecting" anything and just aggregating the entire collection, therefore there is no index to use. I suggest placing an index on "utc_timestamp" and just selecting a few months or a month at a time. Otherwise pre-aggregate in background and use later. Your intended usage is not stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! If I introduce a match (say on the field `document_id`, should I only place an index on that - not both `document_id` and `utc_timestamp` (since covered indexes aren't supported)?

Comment: if you are filtering on some document_id values then you are aggregating only a part of the collection.  What is your intent here? Do you need to aggregate over the full period represented in your collection?  Do new defects even show up "retroactively"?  If you only add data for current day, then you don't need to re-aggregate the past data, as it won't be changing...